# Trying to code custom Throttling function on Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following function which works perfectly fine

```
do {
    try {
        const { assets } = await myApi(arg1, arg2, arg3);     <<--  
        return assets; 
    } catch (err: any) {
        if (err.response.status == 429) {
            await sleep(300);
            console.log('Throttle happened, sleeping for 300ms');
        } else
            throw (err);
    }
}
while (true);
```

I would like to make this method generic and call it in the following way

```
throttleHandler(myApi, ...args)
```

I had some attempts however typescript is complaining about it. I am also not sure if I am doing it correctly. And I don't want to use `any`. I need it to be typed.

```
type ThrottleHandler<TOut> = (...args: any) => TOut;

async function throttleHandler<T>(promiseFunction: ThrottleHandler<T>, ...args: any): Promise<T> {
  console.log("args", args, ...args)
  do {
    try {
      return await promiseFunction(...args);
    } catch (err: any) {

      if (err.response.status == 429) {
        await sleep(300);
        console.log('Throttle happened, sleeping for 300ms');
      } else
        throw (err);
    }
  }
  while (true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type PromiseFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;
type UnwrappedReturnType<T extends PromiseFn> = T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer R> ? R : any

async function throttleHandler<ApiFn extends PromiseFn>(
  promiseFunction: ApiFn,
  ...args: Parameters<ApiFn>
): Promise<UnwrappedReturnType<ApiFn>> {
  console.log("args", args, ...args)
  do {
    try {
      return await promiseFunction(...args);
    } catch (err: any) {

      if (err.response.status == 429) {
        await sleep(300);
        console.log('Throttle happened, sleeping for 300ms');
      } else
        throw (err);
    }
  }
  while (true);
}

const k = (arg1: string, arg2: number) => {
  console.log(arg1);
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

const f = throttleHandler(k, 'param', 12);
```

Previous version was using a new TS 4.5 `Awaited` type, but this one works just as well in all recent versions.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYEsDOEBiA7KBeKACgDpSBDOAczQC4ozsQBtAXQEp8A+WRVDAHgYhOAbgCwAKFCQoAVWwB3OGTCQAJgCUIwAK5xsAFXAR+BqBAAewCNjVoeydFmzcCZy9dv2S5KrXqMHHjc8I4CKNgAZhBwUBrcAPxxUHRCkpJkaCDYAMZQkTq5wCgIuMAAFojAwAA2EAASDGp1cPwAgmAoOOZWNnYOfM6chJJQUGC8TpiFOcWldB1d2AA0o1CkxBTUdDAUZEjaMWjtnTickmw7kwLySirqWrr6RpAnS5zcAN5rOaVoCHViDUEJRCAAiLZoMHLeh+GEbSFsNZqBBQb4SMZjYBwEBotaYqBwbR6XBkBRkFDAcbXLAzObYHybPxscQYzEAXygOTIwBy5SIMTgqUCeIk+MxKEiArgcGIRLQYD+EGIaGAPJ09jwBAALAAmACcHHRBIJZIpVLQdQgYEIAGYAAz2lnigm-bD-QHA0EAcgMlQQ1TqUHK9xsEDUMMtEGtEUo+QQsQd9qQaG9zrZBM5EBqGBdmIqiAU0rg6cza3ZawU5RQQcI2J0EHTFbFEjdqqgAGt8EQtgBGOiquCxmFbXV0bA6JAAIxiQS+Pz+AOVXsIfdLhOJ+gGTjlEA9ADcIHW4A2m+lW38qVKCAWA7UGk0WoQOzDvWA9khvTDe7r00A)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think your answer will be more helpful if you can include some comments and explanation for typing declarations